# Why do xml configs of gradle dependencies go with "Gradle__" prefix? Intellij IDEA 13

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

Java Spring project with Gradle 1.9 and vertx. Local gradle distribution.
Some lines of build.gradle

```
apply plugin 'java'
apply plugin 'groovy'
apply plugin 'idea'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
            ...
            compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.5.RELEASE'
            compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.5.RELEASE'
            compile 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.2.5.RELEASE'
            ...
}
```

I have an existing gradle project downloaded from git with xml configs in .idea/libraries folder named `spring-aop_3_2_5_RELEASE.xml`, for example, where we can find xml tag `<library name="spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE">...</library>`.
After I had imported this project new file `Gradle__spring-aop_3_2_5_RELEASE.xml` appeared with only difference in `name` attribute of the `library` tag: `Gradle: spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE`. So i have duplicate xml configs for dependencies. I wonder why my gradle added that prefix.

Comment: What do you mean by "already downloaded Jars"? Did you manually add some other Jars to the Eclipse project? All dependencies need to be declared in the `dependencies` block, and will be managed by Gradle.

Comment: I meaned, it is imported to IDEA existing Intellij project.

Comment: Why is there an existing IntelliJ project? Importing a Gradle build should create a new IntelliJ project, and you shouldn't manually add dependencies to that project. Instead, you should declare all dependencies in the Gradle build.

Comment: i expressed my thought incorrectly, it is imported gradle project. And there were xml configs in .idea/libraries folder, as i understand, generated from gradle dependencies, for example "cglib_2_2.xml" in which we can find tag `<library name="cglib-2.2">...</library>`. After project had been imported new file "Gradle__cglib.xml" appeared with only difference in `name` attribute of `library` tag: "Gradle: cglib-2.2". So I have no duplicate jars but duplicate xml configs and the main question is how to remove that prefix "Gradle: " in `name` attribute?

Comment: Sounds you had some old XML files lying around. Delete them, and reimport the Gradle build.

Comment: yea, it will work, but what to do with version control? just gitignore this configs?

Comment: It's customary to add IDE files to `.gitignore`, but I'd be surprised if these files were created by the Gradle import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix is hardcoded, IDEA 13 needs a reimport of your old Gradle projects that were created in IDEA 12. It's not obvious, but there will be a notification about it in the next update.

In the Gradle generated project you can exclude the library files from the version control, same for the .iml files that can be also ignored when using Maven. Other files can be still shared (like code style, run configurations, inspection profiles, etc). [Check this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067) for details.